# how to get class constructor argument types as an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

For example, I have a class Summator:

```
export default class Summator {
   constructor(private readonly firstArgument: number, private readonly secondArgument: number) {}

   get sum() {
     return this.firstArgument + this.secondArgument
   }
}
```

if use ConstructorParameters i get tuple [firstArgument: number, secondArgument: number]. how to get not a tuple but an object , for example:

```
{
  firstArgument: number,
  secondArgument: number
}
```

i tried to implement it like this:

```
[K in keyof ConstructorParameters<typeof Summator>]: ConstructorParameters<typeof Summator>[K]
```

but i get next object:

```
{
  0: number,
  1: number
}
```

Comment: where are you declaring for what?

Comment: I am writing a generic HOC for the react component, an object is created inside the HOC that takes arguments. In order to receive arguments when calling the react component, I need to understand exactly which arguments and what type I should pass.  I can provide an HOC example, but it's quite complex. Now I just want to know if it is possible to get the names of the constructor arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh it's not possible that arguments' wildcard names are private (not the `private` keyword) you can't get its name orthodox instead you can use declare an object as an argument like this:

```js
export default class Summator {
  private readonly firstArgument: number;
  private readonly secondArgument: number;

  constructor(options: {
    firstArgument: number;
    secondArgument: number
  }) {
    [this.firstArgument, this.secondArrgument] = [options.firstArgument, options.secondArgument]
  }

  get sum() {
    return this.firstArgument + this.secondArgument
  }
}
```

and

```js
ConstructorParameters<typeof Summator>[0]
```